# .NET DDD Example

Tags: domain-driven-design, sample

Can somebody point me towards a 'complete' DDD example developed on the .NET platform. Most of the examples I find feel 'incomplete'.

I'd really like to see the DDD principles in action.

Comment: I asked this same question a while back and got some decent response. You might [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540130/good-domain-driven-design-samples).

Comment: Here's a fully-fledged example: https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction

Comment: Got one here! https://github.com/appie2go/steal-this-code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try the code that is built as part of the [.NET Domain-Driven Design with C#: Problem - Design - Solution](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/-NET-Domain-Driven-Design-with-C-Problem-Design-Solution.productCd-0470147563.html) book.

The code is freely available from Codeplex [here](http://www.codeplex.com/dddpds) and also on the book's website, and is a fairly feature complete application demonstrating DDD with C#.

From the codeplex site:

> The book is one large case study of a real-world application, named SmartCA, which is a smart client application implemented with the latest .NET technologies and following DDD principles.

Answer (score 9):

.NET DDD Sample from Domain-Driven Design Book by Eric Evans can be found here: http://dddsamplenet.codeplex.com

Szymon (search google for: simon-says-architecture dotCOM) is updating source code almost on daily basis. The last release is from 28th Jan 2010.

Cheers,

Jakub G

Answer (score 3):

These are ASP.NET MVC sample applications -
[here](http://www.tampadev.org/News/Details/ASPNETMVCSampleApplicationsOpenSourceExamplesTutorials)
Worked well enough for me.

Here it`s possible to get book about DDD - 
[here](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly)
(use www.bugmenot.com, if you dont want to register there).

**edit**
'ddd quickly...' ain`t good enough. look for 'ddd tackling complexity in the heart of software'.

Comment: first link could be wrong, this link has a group advertisement and redirect personal web pages of hayden.

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ it is. answered this long ago. internet sometimes changes :)

Comment: absolutely right! argh :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Domain Oriented N-Layered .NET 4.0 Sample App.
By Microsoft - Spain

Using .NET 4.0 C#, Entity Framework 4.0 
Implementing typical DDD architecture & desing patterns

Sample-App Current state - BETA Version. (V0.9 is compatible with VS.2010 RTM, final .NET 4.0 version, Silverlight 4.0, UNITY 2.0 and PEX&MOLES V0.92)

http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/

Comment: Read criticism on this guidance at http://ayende.com/blog/30721/review-microsoft-n-layer-app-sample-part-vndash-cross-cutting-is-a-fine-line