# Seeking pointers to approaches and methodologies for system analysis and design

Tags: dns, communication, analysis, blueprint

I have found quite a few material (books and other stuff online) on how to make UML diagrams. So now I understand UML and the diagramming (with a tool).

However, where I am stuck is the approach / methodology. My hunt for approach / methodology always leads to how to use UML and which diagram fits where. Frankly my intent is to know how to start the journey from putting down the domain understanding (and how) to drafting the blueprint of the system that is ready for the use of developers.

I really don't care if it is UML (good if it is so) or not. I should be able to communicate the target application's domain understanding, it's analysis and eventually it's intended design in as clear terms as possible.

I think there is no *Cast in Stone* way of doing this, however, I am looking for potential approaches / methodologies. Please share pointers to any books / training material that is available for the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are a few resources that may help:**

1. [Domain Driven Design Quickly](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly) (Free summary of Domain Driven Design)
2. [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)

These resources deal with gathering the knowledge of the Domain from domain experts, coming up with terms that are ubiquitous for all parties involved, and then designing the programming model to suit.

**Additionally**, since you mention UML, and if you haven't come across the following book yet, I highly recommend it:

- [UML Distilled 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687)

**Lastly**, in more general terms, I would look further into **[Agile Development Methodologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development).**

Comment: Thank you. Let me look at the material and come back.

Comment: Hi Matt. I have been through the "Domain Driven Design Quickly" eBook and now will do further reading. I find this approach more practical and close to the Domain. I am now searching for some case study or a sample implementation of this approach to get a clearer picture. Please do share if you have any. Many thanks.

Comment: @Kabeer, there are some good suggestions on [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540130/good-domain-driven-design-samples)

Comment: Thanks Matt. In the meanwhile I also came across a thesis titled "Using ADO.NET Entity Framework in Domain-Driven Design: A Pattern Approach" here: http://gupea.ub.gu.se/bitstream/2077/10462/1/gupea_2077_10462_1.pdf