# Sharing code in Unit of Work pattern

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, unit-of-work

This a general question.  I am designing a system using the Unit of Work pattern.  Are there any established patterns which lays out how to share logic between multiple units of work in a unit testable way?

Here is a more concrete scenario:

There is a PurchaseOrder which

> UnitOfWork1 -> submits PO for approval
>
> UnitOfWork2 -> approves or denies PO and sent it back to submitter

Both Unit of works shares same code such as:

> ShareLogic1 -> User needs to have access to PO
>
> SharedLogic2 -> Record the last action to PO

What pattern(s) can I use where such logic can be shared between multiple units of work.  Though inheritance can solve the problem in this case, I don't want to use inheritance as it won't fit in every case.

Comment: This pattern is called methods -) Method is a reusable piece of code.

Comment: That is not what I was asking.  Is there pattern for sharing logic between multiple units of work?  The shared code needs to be mockable.  Its easy to dump the code into a bunch of helper classes but that is not what I was looking for.  The beset solution I was able to come up with is to have a business logic factory which classes for for specific logic the unit of work calls for.  I am not sure if this is the best pattern.  I am pretty sure this is a common scenario and I wanted to know how others tackled this problem.

Comment: I think you misunderstood UnitOfWork pattern, UOF is a SCOPE in which a series of operations can be considered atomic (in simple words), .NET TransactionScope class is an example of UOC for data access. So it's a SCOPE. From what you wrote it looks like that you understood UOC as some sort of WorkFlow elemnt.

Comment: Either you have a mess in you head, or I misunderstood you. If it's first case, then try looking at examples of Domain Driven Design applications. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540130/good-domain-driven-design-samples

Comment: I understand the UnitOfWork pattern.  I think you  misunderstood my question.  If you do not understand the question, please do not comment.

Answer (score 0):

Put that logic in a class and let both units of work have access to it. Both examples seem to belong to a PurchaseOrderRepository class. Using inversion of control you can mock it.