# DDD resources or showcases

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm a strong believer in DDD and really appreciate what it brings to the table. However, I'm having problems selling the idea to other people, mostly to management and to other developers. I want to show simple quick examples that will fit into shorter attention span and may be small reads. Eric Evans talk on DDD is available but its a bit long. I also know about the InfoQ article on DDD Quickly. Is there any other resources that can point me to give quick highlights and may be showcases and make the idea more sellable? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For demonstrating DDD the best resource ought to be the domain model for the project itself.

Since it doesn't exist yet, it's hard to know if it would even be useful for your group of people.

If you had the essential terms of the ubiquitous language written down, a draft of a layered architecture sketched out, and you could present them in a way where everybody feels this naturally would make the project manageable, then they would be sold on the idea before they knew it was DDD.

Comment: +1 like the idea of "then they would be sold on the idea before they knew it was DDD"

Answer (score 2):

Samples:
[Good Domain Driven Design samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540130/good-domain-driven-design-samples)

[cargo dddsample in the blue book](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/)

And the Loan-SharePie sample is also very good in the blue book.