# Documenting architectural design for scalable web apps

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, architecture

I am working on an application that has some scalability requirements and consists of a web-based front-end along with a set of services and workflows.  In the architecture that I have designed, some of these services will perform necessary transformations on a given set of data, pull additional data from a database, and so on.

In terms of documenting my architectural design, I am wondering if someone can suggest a couple books or some reading material on what are the best practices.  I am not looking for a guide on UML.  Let me clarify...

For example: I have a service... let's call it my Workflow service.  It will take a request, read some stuff from a database to look up that request, and trigger a workflow.  Sounds easy enough.  In terms of the architectural design, lets say I break off the database logic into its own module or package... should this just be called the blahblahblahDAO or blahblahblahBusinessObjects?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for deeper insights in how to layer real software and what proper names they should have you should read about `Domain Driven Design`

[First and classic book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) (be aware that it's very general). As for something practical you can check out [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577) or just google for some [online examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540130/good-domain-driven-design-samples).